# Azure - Publishing to a cloned resource

Tags: azure, publish

I have cloned the resource. When trying to publish the WebApp from Visual Studio to the cloned resource, the dialog box doesn't show up the Resource Group or AppService which I created (PFA).

Is there any permission settings needed to configure in azure app service?

Answer (score 0):

If you're publishing from VS, just download the publish profile from the cloned App Service and import in your Visual Studio:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/tutorial-import-publish-settings-azure?view=vs-2019

Comment: Thanks so much for your quick response.

However, I receive the following error-> Error: Could not connect to the remote computer.

I'm assuming I have the permissions configued incorrectly.  But, I don't see where.

Comment: you should be able to deploy using publish profile